# How to render 500 page in rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to send e-mail when having an exception in my application and render the regular 500 page. I could not find how to perform the 500 page render:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError do
     send_email_of_error
     # what goes here? 
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Raising the exception again will likely to what you want:

```
rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
  send_email_of_error
  raise exception
end
```

You could also call `render` to render your own page, [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) have an example doing this.

But why reinvent the wheel? The [exception notifier gem](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) already does this and is customizable and tested.

Comment: that's great. I found the original was not updated for two years. i'll try this version.

Comment: Unfortunately, that turns out to render the error page, but with a status code of 200.

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach that maybe fits your needs:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_500

  def render_500(exception)
    @exception = exception
    render :template => "shared/500.html", :status => 500
  end
end
```

Comment: One should never rescue from Exception.  Use StandardError instead as in Andrew Marshall's answer.

Comment: @dmur it would be helpful for others if you explain your comment. And the question was how to render a 500 page. That is not covered in Andrew Marshalls answer at all. Wether you rescue from Exception or from StandardError - what I never would do because you don't know anything about the error so let it crash and fix it - is not important here. In my answer I should have written "AnyException"

Comment: You're right, here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby